# Configure spring boot app with multiple Kafka consumer clusters each with different SSL configs?

Tags: spring-boot, apache-kafka, spring-kafka, spring-cloud-stream, spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka

I have a single spring boot application which needs to consume data from topics belonging to two different Kafka clusters having separate SSL configs(keystore and trusstore files & locations).

Is it possible to configure this in application.yml/properties file? Using either spring Kafka/spring cloud stream binders/bindings?

Any leads/help understanding on how if yes or if not possible through yaml/properties file?

I was trying to configure 2nd cluster property under spring.cloud.stream.bindings.consumer and 1st one under spring.kafka.consumer and as I have read on the community it only configured the 1st one and not both.